# English to "basic English" translation

Tags: python, nlp, text-generation

I'd like to build something (ideally in Python) that can translate an English sentence into "basic" English.

**Are there any free/open-source tools/frameworks** that can help? If not, what kind of steps can help solve this problem? (e.g., building on existing work like WordNet or pre-trained word embeddings).

By "basic" I mean things like being **concise** (avoiding unnecessary verbiage) and using **well-known words** (without compromising too much on meaning). I might even consider "broken" English, where verbs for example are lemmatised to their root.

The idea is to get something akin to what Wiki have achieved with their [basic English](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_English) versions of articles. And to give one more example, simplifying sentences is one of the services provided by the [Grammarly app](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/engineering/plainly-speaking-a-linguistic-approach-to-simplifying-complex-words/).

---

For example:

**English:**

```
I hurriedly made my way over to the store in order to purchase various garments from there
```

**"Basic" English**

```
I quickly went to the shop to buy clothes
```

**"Broken" English**

```
I quick go shop buy clothes
```

---

Comment: Does this look like text summarization? There could be pretrained models for that.

Comment: This task can also be seen as a special type of machine translation (from "High English" to "Everyday English") so any machine translation tool (with the appropriate language models given) can do the task

Comment: After a bit of research on "text summarization" and all the rabbit holes therein, I may have a plan... given an uncommon word in the sentence (e.g., "*stick* it in the oven"), BERT may allow me to find a list of context-based substitutions ("*put*", "*place*", "*bung*", etc.); from there it may be a case of picking the most commonly occurring word using known word frequencies (e.g., "*put*") and then making a straight substitution?

Answer (score 0):

Text simplification is not as popular as other generative tasks (e.g. summarization, translation). Nevertheless, you may try the approach of the [Keep It Simple: Unsupervised Simplification of Multi-Paragraph Text](https://aclanthology.org/2021.acl-long.498/) paper (ACL'21). The authors released their [source code](https://github.com/tingofurro/keep_it_simple) and [their models](https://huggingface.co/philippelaban/keep_it_simple).